# Validation of java object using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, validation, wicket

I have following task for my project:
I need to **validate a java object, based on rules in a script** (for example javascript).

Why in javascript? 
Because in javascript I can be flexible and create rules as I want (e.g. validating a combination of fields like validate(tax,recipient))

Now here is what I have:

1) I have validation rules defined in a javascript file, Rules.js

```
function checkPrice(price){
  if(price < 0){
    return false;
  }
}
```

2) I have a plain Java Object (Invoice). And it must stay plain!

```
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

  private String details;
  private String tax;
  private String recipient;
  private double price;

  //getter and setter
}
```

3) And I have a ValidatorObject. This can be a java or javascript object. Depending on your suggestion.

This ValidatorObject has a method validate, which has the Javascript Rules File (see Point 1) and the Java Object, Invoice, (see Point 2) as parameters.

```
validate(Rules.js, Invoice i){

  //here it must take the Rules.js and use the rules inside to validate the Invoice i 

}
```

So my question would be:
Are there any frameworks that I can use to validate a Java Object based on rules defined in a javascript file? Or any tutorials, videos or suggestions?

Or how can I read a javascript file into a java object? Are there any getters or setters for javascript?

Anything would be nice!

Regards,
Dave

Comment: why javascript is needed? why not java for writing rules??

Comment: Can you give an example of how using Javascript is helps `be flexible and create rules as I want`? The example you gave would be simpler in Java.

Comment: You can use Rhino to execute JavaScript from Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey 1) Because I am using Apache Wicket as the web application framework, to build forms and so on, 2) Because I need a declarative approach, the assistant from the university wants it so...

Comment: I still don't why you can't do both of those things dynamically in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Rhino! where I can read and manipulate my javascript file...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to embed a ScripEngine into Java Application:

```
import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;



public static void main( String[] args )
   throws
      ScriptException, IOException
{
   final String run;
   if( args.length > 0 )
   {
      run = args[0];
      if( run.contains( "=" ))
      {
         usage();
      }
   }
   else
   {
      run = "run.js";
   }
   File script = new File( run );
   if( script.canRead())
   {
      ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType( "text/javascript" );
      Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings( ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE );
      bindings.put( "controller", new Controller());
      for( int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i )
      {
         String[] varVal = args[i].split( "=" );
         if( varVal.length == 2 )
         {
            bindings.put( varVal[0], varVal[1] );
         }
         else
         {
            usage();
         }
      }
      info( "Loading and executing: " + script );
      engine.put( ScriptEngine.FILENAME, script.toString());
      engine.eval( new FileReader( script ));
   }
   else
   {
      System.err.println( "Can't read automation script file: " + script );
      usage();
   }
}
```

In this case the Controller Java class exposes some public methods to JavaScript to use the flexibility of the interpreted code coupled to the robustness of compiled Java code.

Comment: I heard I can use Rhino too. but what is the difference? Is Rhino not a part of the java script library?